# How to grep for three periods in OSX?

Tags: regex, macos, grep

I'm on OSX 10.9.3 and trying to grep for three periods, not the specific ellipsis character.

This command just returns everything:

```
grep -r '\.\.\.' ./
```

Comment: That looks fine to me.  Are you sure you've cut & pasted exactly the command you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fgrep handles fixed patterns

```
fgrep -r '...' [pathname]
```

rather than what grep does - use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -rE '[\.]{3}' ./
```